# elisp - How to dump plist to property value pairs

Tags: print, property-lists

Below example dump it as a list, but I wish to dump it in property value pairs:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output
(defun dump-plist(obj level)
  (if (listp obj)
      (dolist (item obj)
        (dump-plist item (1+ level)))
    (progn
      (while (> level 1)
        (princ "  ")
        (setq level (1- level)))
      (princ obj)
      (princ "\n"))))

(defun test()
  (let* ((my-plist (list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :more (list 4 5 6))))
    (print my-plist)
    (dump-plist my-plist 0)
    ))

(test)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example

(:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :more (4 5 6))
:a
1
:b
2
:c
3
:more
  4
  5
  6
#+end_example
```

expected output is:

```
:a 1
:b 2
:c 3
:more (4 5 6)
```

Comment: Either iterate or recurse over the list a pair of entries at a time, not a single entry at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code block with this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output
(defun dump-plist(obj)
    (unless (null obj)
        (princ (format "%s %s\n" (car obj)  (cadr obj)))
        (dump-plist (cddr obj))))

(defun test()
    (let* ((my-plist (list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :more (list 4 5 6))))
        (print my-plist)
        (dump-plist my-plist)))

(test)
#+END_SRC
```

It goes recursively through your plist and prints two entries at once until the list is empty

This works because `plist` means `paired list`. This implicates that this list has always a equal number of entries.

Replacing `princ` with `format` saves some lines of code.
The second parameter `level` is not needed anymore and therefore omitted.

Comment: Officially `plist` means "property list", not "paired list". But yeah, it should always have an even number of entries regardless of what you call it.